# Replacing published branch

Tags: git, branch

Suppose there is an upstream project that does not use git, and that I am maintaining a codebase based on this project's released tarballs. I maintain a git branch `master` and my branch `my` from it. I publish both branches in a public git repository. Whenever upstream makes a new major release, I create a new commit on `master` that is identical to that released tarball. I then work on merging the head of `master` into `my`, and publish both branches.

Now suppose that upstream finally comes to their senses and makes their git repository public. I'd like to have my `master` track and become identical to upstream's from this point in history and onwards. What is the recommended course of action? Do I have to simply make a `master-2` that is identical to upstream, and merge it into `my` from there on, abandoning the old `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local repository, you can:

- Delete the branch using `git branch`, then (if you want) create a new 'master' branch.
- Rename the branch to something else using `git branch`, then optionally create a new one.
- Directly re-point the 'master' branch to any commit you want, using `git branch` or `git reset`.

For a remote repository, you can:

- Delete the branch (push a deletion) using `git push --delete`.
- Overwrite the branch with any commit you want, using `git push --force`.

If you do this to a remote repository which is used by other people or systems:

- If you use a different name, other people can easily `git checkout` the new branch, but they might not notice the change and get confused as to why there is suddenly zero activity in the 'master' branch.
- If you instead put a different history in the same 'master' branch, everybody will notice it – but depending on `git` version and the update command they used, it will either stop with an error message (requiring some manual cleanup) or attempt to merge both histories (requiring more manual cleanup).